# Ошибка при функции ILIKE

Tags: python, postgresql

`sql = cur.execute(f'SELECT * FROM main_parse_user WHERE bio LIKE "bla bla bla"')`

Работаю на Python при наборе выдает такую ошибку

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\zufar\AppData\Roaming\JetBrains\PyCharmCE2022.3\scratches\scratch_12.py", line 15, in <module>
    sql = cur.execute(f'SELECT * '
psycopg2.errors.UndefinedColumn: ОШИБКА:  столбец "Jen%" не существует
LINE 1: SELECT * FROM main_parse_user WHERE bio LIKE "Jen%"
```

Но это же не столбец

Работаю по [документации](https://itdoxy.com/%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80-postgresql-like/)

Comment: «Работаю по документации» — дайте ссылку на документацию, которая учила вас писать LIKE таким образом

Comment: @andreymal исправил)

Comment: В документации всё правильно, там другие кавычки используются. А в вашем коде кавычки не те

Comment: @andreymal о, спасибо но теперь оно выводит None как мне взять информацию

Comment: Читайте это в документации к используемому вами python-модулю

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ошибка в синтаксисе запроса. В PostgreSQL в двойных кавычках (") указывается имя столбца, имя таблицы и т.д. А в одинарных (') указываются строковые константы.

Т.е. правильный запрос

```
SELECT * FROM "table" WHERE "column" ILIKE '%строка%';
```

В общем случае двойные кавычки можно не указывать, если можно однозначно определить имена столбцов и таблиц.

Comment: Все получилось), но проблема в том что выводит None при print() этого значения

Comment: Ну значит у вас запрос такой.  Если судить по тексту ошибки в тексте вопроса, то вы ищете запись в которой в поле bio есть данные которые начинаются с подстроки 'Jen'. Действительно такая запись есть в таблице?

Comment: Все проблему решил. Надо было после добавить a = cur.fetchall()
А можно ли  '%строка%' добавить несколько слов?